# How to pass image file in Multi-Part Requests as http body parameter(POST)

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

I geeting Image from my gallery, Now want to use this image as in Http body parameters using `Multipart` Request. I didn't able to figured out what I should pass for Image in Multipart request.

My variable `image` contain my gallery image after method call.

```
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
  File? image;
  var fileContent;
  var fileContentBase64;
```

Showing the image in my App

```
   Padding(
       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
          child: image == null? Text("No file chosen"): Image.file(
                              File(image!.path),
                              width: 150,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                    ),
```

Function to get image from gallery

```
void filePicker() async {
final File? selectedImage =
    await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
print(selectedImage!.path);
setState(() {
  image = selectedImage;
  
   fileContent = image!.readAsBytesSync();
   fileContentBase64 = base64.encode(fileContent); 
});
}
```

Now in Api Function how should I use it ?

```
  Future<void> SaveCustomTestBooking() async {


var jsonResponse;
if (EncUserId.isNotEmpty) {
   var postUri = Uri.parse("http://myAPIstomTestBooking");
  var request  = http.MultipartRequest('POST',postUri);
  request.fields['VisitDate'] = '_selectedDate';
  request.fields['EncUserId'] = 'EncUserId';

    request.files.add(new http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
    "UserFile", File(image!.path).readAsBytesSync(),
    filename:"Image.jpg",
    contentType: MediaType('image', 'jpg')));

   request.send().then((response){
     if (response.statusCode == 200) {

       print("Uploaded!");
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DieticianAfterDateSelectPage(rresponse:DieticianEncBookingIdModel.fromJson(jsonResponse),)));
       
   } else {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text("Somthing went wrong")));
    throw Exception("Faild to fetch");

   }
   }


   );}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code example of using image as in Http body parameters using Multipart Request.

```
  request.files.add(new http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
        "thumbnail", File(thumbnailImage.path).readAsBytesSync(),
        filename:"Image.jpg",
        contentType: MediaType('image', 'jpg')));
```

here "thumbnail" is json keyword name. use your own. Thanks